# What’s so funny about "You are winner"?

Tags: grammaticality, slang, colloquialisms, humor, non-native-english

I came across one slang thing:
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=You%27re%20Winner!

While understand that it is grammatically incorrect and you must say "You are the winner", I don't get what’s so funny about it. It does not even change the sense of the sentence much.

I mean nobody laughs at you if you say "I am student" or something like that. What's the deal?

I was surprised when AVGN (a popular Youtube show) made fun about it in this video around 7:40. He acts like it is soooooooo funny, but I just don't get it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6DtVHqyYts

Comment: It is subjective how funny something is.

Comment: Of course, but even if something is not funny for you you can understand why other people can laugh at it. That's not the case with this thing. And I'm not alone by the way, seems that most non-english speakers don't get this one.

Comment: I see a pattern, then.  It is something native English speakers find funny.  I myself find many things non-English speakers say very funny.  Also, this question is off-topic because it's about you getting upset about something.

Comment: upset? what? This question about the meaning of slang/colloquialism joke.

Comment: You are asking why something is funny.  That's not a question about English, and it does not have an answer.  Things are funny because they make people laugh.

Comment: I'm asking why the grammatical mistake in English sentence can be considered funny, not why it is funny on its own. If it would be grammatically correct "You are the winner" or "You win" nobody would care(as in most games/sports).

Comment: Something tells me that Internet memes, as well as AVGN, are not a good fit for this site. And plus, as @GeorgePompidou said, the humor in both is entirely subjective. [In case you really want to attempt to understand the meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/a-winner-is-you)

Comment: Ok, I'm quite fulfilled, it makes a little sense for me now :)
Maybe it's better not really topic for this site.
Anyway, thanks for discussion :)

Comment: @Artyom: Your particular example isn't inherently funny to all Anglophones, by any means. But firstly some Anglophones both notice and like to mock the tendency for Russian speakers in particular to omit articles like this (*"In Russia, bomb disarms **you**"*, etc.). Secondly, it's just another variant of the all-time classic [*"All your base are belong to us"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us), mocking non-native speakers in general.

Comment: Artyom Kolichenkov, “you are winner” seems like something that **Borat** would say. So does "I am student".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue is in the part of the description you linked to:

> Upon completion of the race (In version 1.0 the opposing truck would never move)

you would be declared the winner. Hardly a mighty achievement if the opposing truck stood still!

Also the [Engrish](http://www.engrish.com) feel of the phrase is funny.

**EDIT** 
I should emphasize that (in my experience at least) there's nothing malicious or critical about the way people find these things "funny". Rather, it's the sheer delight that comes from the sudden surprise of something being done in an unusual way. It's related to the effect experienced when someone learning a language "invents" a phrase that's perfectly logical but not idiomatic, i.e., "we don't say it like that around here". With Engrish the effect is doubled or exponentially increased, because the surprise is two-fold: "that's not grammatical, *and even if it was, we wouldn't say it like that around here!*".

Often, too, the intended meaning remains crystal clear, which somehow adds further to the delight. My first encounter with Engrish was the now-legendary All Your Base phenomenon. For anyone not familiar with this, it's worth reproducing some text I found describing it on the allyourbase website a while back:

> Basically, a very good Sega Genesis game titled "Zero Wing" (a side
>   scrolling sci-fi shoot 'em up ported from an arcade game) fell victim
>   to poorly translated subtitles for the opening cinema.
>
> A (human?) spaceship is exploding because (per the mechanic) "somebody
>   set up us the bomb."  An alien overlord named "Cats" appears after the
>   operator declares, "we get signal, main screen turn on," and Cats then
>   tells the Captain of the doomed ship, "you have no chance to survive,
>   make your time," after informing him that, "all your base are belong
>   to us."
>
> (I omit here several other funny catch phrases in the interest of
>   brevity) The captain, in final desperation, orders the launch of his
>   fighters, called "Zigs," blessing the pilots with his words of
>   confidence, "you what you doing, take off every Zig.  For great
>   justice."  When you start playing, you pilot your Zig away from the
>   final explosion of your mother-ship.

[allyourbase.com](http://www.allyourbasearebelongtous.com/)

Comment: While it is reasonable to say so, I find Engrish a little bit different because in the case of Engrish the meaning of sentence becomes absurd, but here it is just grammar mistake that doesn't make much difference.

Comment: You have to consider the context of the Engrish being in a game, in this case after finishing a race. Essentially, your reward for finishing a race (where your opponent doesn't move) is a quick screen with a trophy and a butchered Engrish sentence.

Comment: well... maybe it makes a little sense for me now :) Thanks!

Comment: It's not the grammar mistake itself that's funny.  The grammar mistake is just a device used to indirectly refer to the game's ludicrous proclamation that you are a winner after having done nothing- a potato could have won that race.

Comment: Also, I'd say in Engrish the *meaning* doesn't always become absurd, but the *effect* can still be hilarious! But Engrish is not the main point about this one, I think. Calling someone a winner when no race is being run is part of it ("you tied your shoes today" in the example you linked to), and likening the person's achievement to that of the player in the game where the phrase originated is another.